# Get lines which don't end with semi-colon from a file

Tags: bash, scripting

I am trying to check the ends of code for semi-colons as they are causing me some issues for a server I have running. To do this I am using a bash script (as I am more familiar with bash) to read through the lines and return those that doesn't end with a semi-colon. My bash script is as follows

```
while read line
do
if[$line!=*;]
echo $line
fi
done < $1
```

When I run the script, it says there is an error by `fi` but I cannot figure it out. I also realize this will return statements like `if` and `while` but that will be fine for my needs.

Given the sample input

```
use CGI;

print "<html>"
print "<head>";
print "</head>";
print "<body><p> HELLO WORLD </p>";
print "</body>";
print "</html>"
```

this should be the output

```
print "<html>"
print "</html>"
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using `grep`?

Comment: honestly forgot about grep

Comment: would you post a sample input file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be with grep. Given an `input.txt` file like this:

```
spam
foo;<Space><Space>
sausage
baked;<Tab>
beans
unladen;
```

You could do

```
grep -v ';\s*$' input.txt
```

and obtain

```
spam
sausage
beans
```

grep's `-v` flag means "return all lines not matching this regular expression", so it will skip all lines ending with semi-colons.

If your lines have also spaces after the semi-colons, the `\s*` means "any sequence of space characters" so grep will remove those lines aswell.

Comment: Looks like he wants to exclude those lines, `grep -v`.

Comment: that seems to be returning my entire program not just the lines without semi-colons

Comment: maybe there are spaces after the `;` character?

Comment: doesn't seem like it guess I'll have to do it the old fashioned way. Thanks for your help @Ju Liu

Answer (score 2):

The reason you have a problem is that your `if` statement requires a `then`.  You also need some more spaces and to quote your variables.  It still won't work, though.  Your comparison is wrong, too - that's not how `[` works to compare strings.  You can use bash's `[[` instead:

```
while read line
do
  if [[ "$line" != *\; ]]
  then
    echo "$line"
  fi
done < $1
```

But even with all that, what you really *should* be doing is:

```
grep -v ';$' $1
```

Answer (score 0):

To search lines with semicolon `;`  and without semicolon  in a linux file

[image]

```
$ grep ';' file_name

$ grep -v ';\s*$' file_name
```